# Install failure of youtube-dl on a Mac

Tags: mac, osx-el-capitan, youtube-dl

I am trying to install youtube-dl in OS X El Capitan with curl.

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

  %  Total   %  Received % Xferd Average  Speed     Time      Time       Time     Current         
                                 Dload   Upload     Total     Spent      Left     Speed 
  0     3    0     0     0     0     0       0  ーー:ーー:ーー 0:00:02 ーー:ーー:ーー      0
  0     3    0     0     0     0     0       0  ーー:ーー:ーー 0:00:03 ーー:ーー:ーー      0
100   582    0   582     0     0    86       0  ーー:ーー:ーー 0:00:06 ーー:ーー:ーー    181
  0 1278k    0     0     0     0     0       0  ーー:ーー:ーー 0:00:10 ーー:ーー:ーー      0
Warning: Failed to create the file /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl: No such file or directory. 
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely, that you don't have write-permissions where you want to store the downloaded file.

However you don't want to install manually.

Try installing it with pip:

1. Install python pip
2. Do `pip install youtube-dl`
3. Then - when the need arises - you can update it conveniently using `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`

Comment: Getting the same error . How to give access to the files.?

Comment: Check your permissions for the folder in question, first:
`ls -lAh /usr/local/bin`
should give you something like this:
`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K Aug 18 07:13 /usr/local/bin`.

You can change ownership of files and folders using the command `chown` and permissions by using the command `chmod`.

Example according to your question:
`sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin`
`sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin`